# How can I put an Example Object in my open api php docs

Tags: php, symfony, swagger

I want to put in this code an example object,  I have no idea how to do it and I can't find any documentation either:

```
#[OA\Response(
    response: 200,
    description: 'wages response',
    content: new OA\JsonContent(
        type: 'array',
        items: new OA\Items(ref: new Model(type: Employee\Wage::class, groups: ['view']))
    )
)]
```

I want to do it like this one in JAVA, in java the property to be able to enter an example response body is @ExampleObject:

```
@Operation(summary = "Lista todas las categorías")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200",
                    description = "Se han encontrado categorías",
                    content = { @Content(mediaType = "application/json",
                            array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(implementation = CategoriaDto.class)),
                            examples = {@ExampleObject(
                                    value = """
                                                [
                                                    {"id": 1, "nombre": "Veggie"},
                                                    {"id": 2, "nombre": "Carne"},
                                                    {"id": 3, "nombre": "Pescado"}
                                                ]
                                            """
                            )}
                    )}),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404",
                    description = "No se ha encontrado ninguna categoría",
                    content = @Content),
    })
```

But I couldn't do it

Comment: Do you use NelmioApiDocBundle ?